# How can I select the 3rd column for each table row?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, watin

I´m trying to get the values of TDs inside a table using WatiN. The problem is that I´m not able to select a table by Id (because it´s missing). Can I select it based on class?

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 BORDER=0 class="TABLEBORDER">
<TR>

<TH class=HEADTEXT>
Target
</TH>
<TH class=HEADTEXT>
Trigger<br>enabled?
</TH>
<TH class=HEADTEXT>
Account
</TH>
<TH class=HEADTEXT>
Password<br>changed?

</TH>
<TH class=HEADTEXT>
Error message<br>(if any)
</TH>
<!-- S_STATUS_ROW -->

<TR>

<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
RACF
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
No
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
USERNAME1
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
Yes
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
&nbsp;

</TD>
<!-- S_STATUS_ROW -->

<TR>

<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
Domain Name
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
No
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
FirstName.LastName
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
Yes
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
&nbsp;

</TD>
<!-- S_STATUS_ROW -->

<TR>

<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
NotesWeb
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
No
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
USERNAME1
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
Yes
</TD>
<TD valign=top class=CELLTEXT>
&nbsp;

</TD>
<!-- S_STATUS_CONTENT_BOTTOM -->
</TABLE>
```

There are other tables in the page. The one that I am interested is the only one that is formatted like above and I am only interested in the 3rd Column (where it says YES.. if there is a problem then it will say NO).

The table above is the only one with the class=TABLEBORDER
how can I access the 3rd column of every table row?

Comment: Try out loading this as XML into `XDocument.Load("....")` and then use linq-to-xml

Comment: Sounds like an plan. Do you have any sample code to demo this? I've tried linq in the past and small projects became overly complex

Comment: `XDocument` won't load such document, look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for HTML parsing

Comment: I looked at HTML Agility Pack. It can find all the YES/NO's but I need to know if each YES is on a row. I need it to say 1 YES per TableRow.

Comment: @CocoaDev You can use linq to xml using this solution: add a root tag before using linq to xml and then your document is an xml document

Comment: What is a root tag? I'm not familiar with linq. Also you may answer the question in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the table, use `Find.ByClass()`

There are a number of ways to get the values of a particular column, but for simplicity's sake  I tend to just iterate through the table rows; easy to understand now and 6 months from now when you come back to the code.

**Code**: Print to the console the content of the 4th column (the Yes values in the HTML above), the loop starts at 1, not 0, so the first row is ignored as TH elements are not seen as table cells.

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo("[yourURL]");

Table theTable = browser.Table(Find.ByClass("TABLEBORDER"));

for (int i = 1; i < theTable.OwnTableRows.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("column value:" + theTable.OwnTableRows[i].TableCells[3].Text);
}
```

The above has been tested on WatiN2.1, IE9, Win7

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Find.BySelector("")`, which is very similar to JQuery. For example:

```
var element = browser.Element(Find.BySelector("Table TD"));
```

Comment: Im not familiar with JQuery. Will look in to it